# is Message thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, jms

Section 2.14 of JMS 2.0 Spec:

> JMS could have required that all its objects support concurrent use.
>   Since support for concurrent access typically adds some overhead and
>   complexity, the JMS design restricts its requirement for concurrent
>   access to those objects that would naturally be shared by a
>   multi-threaded client. The remaining objects are designed to be
>   accessed by one logical thread of control at a time.

Supports Concurrent usage:
Destination, ConnectionFactory, Connection

Does not support concurrent usage:
JMSContext, Session, Producer, consumer

Not sure why thread safety of Message is not discussed in spec?

**EDIT**

Is Message thread safe? Can two threads share it without race?

No. Message is not thread safe. It should not be shared between threads.

Comment: Why would you need access to the same Message object in multiple threads? In particular modify a Message in multiple thread. You could allow concurrent reads for multiple consumers.

Comment: It would we safe to share the message between threads, unless they try to modify the message

Comment: scenario - two threads processing payload and setting message property. Can it be done in parallel without race?

Comment: @AmitG That is a very strange use case. But no, it can't be done with a JMS message.

Comment: @nos haven't really figured out why multithreading behavior of message is missing from spec.

Comment: @AmitG See chapter 6.2 where it says that any object created by a session is not thread safe. Messages are created by a session (either explicitly, or implicitly from another object created by a session). You can do your own locking to access it from multiple threads though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message is not thread-safe. Message is mutable, it has setters, so while one thread is using a Message another thread can interfere and change it.

Comment: I did look into open-source implementation of JMS-spec, figured that Message is not safe. Wonder why it not spec?